Problema al desplegar proyecto VUE3
tengo un crud desarrollado con VUE 3 pero al ejecutar el comando npm run build y querer desplegarlo en github pages o vercel me sale totalmente en blanco el index.html, ya he intentado muchas cosas, revisar la configuracion en el archivo vue.config.js, las rutas, etc. y no he pdido dar con el problema. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.
comparto el repositorio de github: https://github.com/miguelfb19/crud.git
Archivo vue.config.js:


const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/crud/'
    : '/'
})



Adicionalmente dejo la configuración de mi archivo de rutas:


import App from './App.vue'
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'

//Importar los componentes
import EntryData from '@/components/EntryData'
import tablaDatos from '@/components/tablaDatos'
import buscarEmpleados from '@/components/buscarEmpleados'
import welcomeComponent from '@/components/welcomeComponent'
import ErrorComponent from '@/components/ErrorComponent'
import eliminarEmpleado from '@/components/eliminarEmpleado'

//Crear las rutas
const routes = [
    {path: '/home', component: welcomeComponent},
    {path: '/', component: welcomeComponent},
    {path: '/form', component: EntryData},
    {path: '/table', component: tablaDatos},
    {path: '/search', component: buscarEmpleados},
    {path: '/delete', component: eliminarEmpleado},
    {path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', component: ErrorComponent}, //el '/:pathMatch(.*)*' sirve para crear una ruta comodín (se usa comunmente para crear pagina de error)
    //{path: '/nombreRuta', component: nombreComponente},
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')



Tambien intente desplegar directamente la carpeta dist en un repositorio diferente y me envia directamente a la ruta de error que configure y no pasa de ahi.
Muchas gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! en github no se.. pero vercel no tiene un tuto para desplegar vue?

Ya hice las modificaciones necesarias, no se si alla quedado mejor?

El tuto de vercel no sirvio??? probaste una app simple a ver si es algo en las rutas?? es mas, probaste desplegar con una sola ruta?? esto: https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-vuejs-to-vercel no te sirvio?

Hola,  ya he intentado todas las cosas que mencionaste y ninguna me ha funcionado, no entiendo que puede estar mal con el proyecto, cuando lo habro localmente funciona con normalidad

No se que decirte.. si ellos no pueden ayudarte yo no se como se despliega ahi.. igual es raro lo que decis.. si local no tenes problemas de rutas, que hace tu pagina que si genera error desplegada? tenes un back?
